# WCF SOAP large files and connectivity issues

Tags: xml, wcf, soap

I was wondering if this scenario is possible to solve it with WCF+SOAP.

I have a WCF method using SOAP and BasicHttpsBinding in the server part.

this method returns a response of 20MB size.

It is not too much for a broadband but the client connection sometimes is slow and even some times the Internet connection goes down.

I would like that if the Internet connection goes down the WCF client restarts the connection when possible, and continues downloading the response, but not from the beggining.

Is this possible in WCF? or do I need to create a .txt file with the response and try to develope a kind of download manager?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can overtake this using Reliable Messaging in WCF

```
(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733136%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
```

Although, reliable messaging is not suitable for Load Balanced environments for non load balanced environments this is awesome.

For transferring large files consider using MTOM encoding

```
(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395209%28v=vs.110%29.aspx),
```

these two combination is what you are after :)